# How to prevent Eclipse from forgetting settings?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, syntax, ide, syntax-highlighting

I am using Eclipse Luna on Mac OS and I've installed the Eclipse Color Theme plug-in. After choosing the color theme that I liked, I edit it under the Eclipse->Preferences->Java->Editor->Syntax Coloring, where I disable Bold for all syntax elements.

The thing is that, after I close and restart Eclipse, all the Syntax Coloring changes I've made were lost, and it's back with the old ones...

So, how can I prevent Eclipse from forgetting these settings?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know Eclipse saves every setting in the "workspace". If you switch workspaces your style wont save between workspaces. If you are in the same workspace, then I don't know why its not saving.